# Doctrine loadClassMetadata

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

Strange problem.

I have an entity which has property set up by Doctrine loadClassMetadata:

```
App\EventListener\DrinkEventListener:
    arguments:
        - { drinkImagesWebPath: '%env(DRINK_IMAGE_WEB_PATH)%', appUrl: '%env(APP_URL)%' }
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

I changed argument to normal parameter ('%app_url%'), no luck.

DrinkEventListener:

```
...
public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    Drink::$appUrl = $this->appUrl;
    Drink::$drinkImageWebPath = $this->drinkImagesWebPath;
}
```

The problem is, when I clear Symfony cache with warmup, then these properties are empty. Event handler is executed though.

When I clear cache with no-warmup, these properties exist.